# PHP special character becoming bad

Tags: php, mysql

I am have a database that is running fine on website, but when I run it on my xampp for wordpress it is showing single quote `'` as `â€™` . While database also has `â€™` in table, and there is smooth mysql_fetch_array is using to display data, but my xampp and wordpress not showing `â€™` as `'` single quote, please let me know how can I solve this issue. ?

Comment: Look for encoding and charsets.

Comment: Are you sure you're using `'` and not one of these? `“ ” ‘ ’`